# Python, MySQL: how to populate an empty column with values from python array (aka list)?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have an int list `lst = [1, 2, 3]`

And a mysql table with an empty second column:

```
key value
a 
b
c
```

I want to populate the `value` column with values from my list so as to make the table look like this:

```
key value
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

To do that, I use `cursor.execute` function:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (value) VALUES %s", lst)
```

But an error is always popping up: **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**. I  tried to place item between square brackets (see last line), but no luck either: **_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB s
erver version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1")**

How am I to fix this issue and populate the empty column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (value) VALUES %s", (item,) )`

Comment: That `insert` will not add those values to the existing rows; it will (if it works) create new rows. An `update` that specified which row (with a `where` clause) is needed.

Comment: Actually, how does `lst` relate to `item`? Are you iterating this list in code you've not shown?